# How repair method delete element from bst without generic type and no flag

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, element

I search solution of my problem, my algorithm code delete element from Binary Search tree doesn't work properly. I don't know, where is error in this code and how it should be to work

```
public void usun(int wartosc) { 
korzen = usunrekord(korzen, wartosc);
}
private Wezel usunrekord(Wezel korzen, int wartosc1) {
if (korzen == null)
return korzen;
if (wartosc1 < korzen.getWartosc()) {
korzen.setLewy(usunrekord(korzen.getLewy(), wartosc1));
if (wartosc1 > korzen.getWartosc())
            korzen.setPrawy(usunrekord(korzen.getPrawy(), wartosc1));
        else {
             if (korzen.getLewy() == null)
             return korzen.getPrawy();
             else if (korzen.getPrawy() == null)
             return korzen.getLewy();
             korzen.setWartosc(znajdzMin());
             korzen.setPrawy(usunrekord(korzen.getPrawy(), korzen.getWartosc()));
        }
return korzen;
    }
return korzen;
}
```

Class Node, create tree binary search based on it

```
public class Wezel {
private int wartosc;
private Wezel lewy;
private Wezel prawy;

public Wezel(int wartosc) {
    this.wartosc = wartosc;
}

public int getWartosc() {
    return wartosc;
}

public void setWartosc(int wartosc) {
    this.wartosc = wartosc;
}

public Wezel getLewy() {
    return lewy;
}

public void setLewy(Wezel lewy) {
    this.lewy = lewy;
}

public Wezel getPrawy() {
    return prawy;
}
public void setPrawy(Wezel prawy) {
    this.prawy = prawy;
}
}
```

Comment: I wanted to help, but I cannot understand your code. Apart of the formatting, I cannot understand the naming, and that confuses me. I have no idea what a "Wezel" is, or a "prawy" or a "Weze lewy". Of course naming should not stop me to understand the code, but if you want help, give names that are helping the reader to understand the code. Once I read: "code like the one who will maintain it is a serial killer that knows where you live".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.